# How to get my JButtons to be on the left and not in the middle

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I'm a little lost here, when I run the program the buttons are in the middle of the input and not directly on the bottom aligned with it.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I'm also trying to find out how to get statistics for my input like min and max value, and average word size.  I'm a little lost, thanks!

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class CopyTextPanel extends JPanel
{
private JTextField input;
private JLabel output, inlabel, outlabel;
private JButton compute, clear;
private JPanel panel, panel1, panel2;

public CopyTextPanel()
{
    setLayout (new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    inlabel = new JLabel("Input:  ");
    outlabel = new JLabel("Text Statistics Result: ");
    input = new JTextField (50);
    output = new JLabel();
    compute = new JButton("Compute Statistics");
    compute.addActionListener (new ButtonListener());
    clear = new JButton("Clear Text");
    clear.addActionListener (new ButtonListener());
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel2 = new JPanel();

    output.setMaximumSize (new Dimension(500, 30));
    output.setMinimumSize (new Dimension(500, 30));
    panel.setMaximumSize (new Dimension(500, 30));
    panel.setMinimumSize (new Dimension(500, 30));
    panel.setBackground(Color.gray);
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    panel.add(inlabel);
    panel.add(input);
    panel1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel1, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    panel1.add(compute);
    panel1.add(clear);
    add (Box.createRigidArea (new Dimension(0, 10)));
    panel2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel2, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    panel2.add(outlabel);
    panel2.add(output);
    setMaximumSize (new Dimension(600, 250));
    setMinimumSize (new Dimension(600, 250));
    setBackground(Color.white);
    add (panel);
    add (panel1);
    add (panel2);
}

private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
    {

        String inputText = input.getText();//sets what is typed by the user 
to a String object

        String[] splitted = inputText.trim().split("\\p{javaSpaceChar}
{1,}");//makes a String array, and trims all the whitespaces from the user 
input
        int numberofWords = splitted.length;//it then sets splitted length 
to an integer
        String numow = Integer.toString(numberofWords);// finally it makes 
the numberofwords int into a string 
        Arrays.sort(splitted);
        if (event.getSource()==compute)//if the user presses the compute 
button
        {
            output.setText (numow + " words; " );//the output is the string 
of integers of how many words were typed
        }
        else//if the user presses another button
            input.setText(" "); // clear text filed after copying
    }
}
}
```

Comment: How should the output look like? Post an image / ascii art of it and if resizable with more space

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/sGcRP  this is what it's supposed to look like, he says he doesn't want anything to move when resizing the window which I've gotten done, and color doesn't matter.

Comment: First of all, I'd consider using a `GridBagLayout`, it's more flexible.  If it's too complicated, then you'd need to consider using compound layouts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So based on the desired result...

[image: Desired Result]

I would recommend considering using a series of panels, dedicated to generating the layout requirements for each row, then wrapping those together into a single container.

For my money, `GridBagLayout` presents the most flexible option, while also presenting one of the more complicated at the same time.

This example focuses solely on the layout requirements, you'll have to figure out how to apply the functionality to it later.

[image: Example output]

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() throws HeadlessException {
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
            JPanel fieldPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

            JTextField inputField = new JTextField("Computer Science 1");
            fieldPane.add(new JLabel("Input Text:"), gbc);
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            fieldPane.add(inputField, gbc);

            JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);

            buttonPane.add(new JButton("Computer Statistics"), gbc);
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            buttonPane.add(new JButton("Clear Text"), gbc);

            JPanel resultsPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);

            resultsPane.add(new JLabel("Text Statistics Result:"));
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            resultsPane.add(new JLabel("3 words"), gbc);

            gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

            add(fieldPane, gbc);
            add(buttonPane, gbc);
            add(resultsPane, gbc);
        }

    }

}
```

I strongly recommend having a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details about how various layout managers work

Comment: dude...thank you so much, i was just about to close this laptop because I was getting so frustrated, you just helped me out in a big way.  I'm going to have to research the layouts a little more.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Layout is complicated at the best of times, no one layout manager will do everything your need. You will need to use different techniques, like compound layouts, taking advantage of the power of the individual layout managers to achieve a given, isolate result and then building the layout up from there

Comment: 1+ I agree, once I've learnt how to use `GridBagLayout` I found I've been using it more lately. I'm at work so I couldn't answer this but I love to read your answers :)

Comment: yeah man you busted this out quick, I really appreciate you taking the time to help me, I still don't understand how it works but I'm going to drill this into my brain

Answer (score 0):

You should use Layouts such as BorderLayout that might help you.
Change the JPanels by doing `panel.add(new JButton("East"),BorderLayout.EAST);`
etc.. I hope it helps. If you dont use layouts they will end up randomized.

Comment: That would place A button on the right - if you want more, then you'd need another container to wrap the buttons - just saying ;)